# Spring cloud gateway to forward request if its coming from whitelisted domain

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have zuul already in place to route the services i am stuck with domain filtering

I want a request to go through my endpoint only if its coming through whitelisted domain

**Ex
pass request if its coming from https://example.com
Block it : if its coming from any other domain (https://example1.com**)

Can we do it through cloud gateway or is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot prevent this. The only part you can control is the host value in the header, but they can manipulate the host value.

Comment: you can do ip check, maybe it will work

Comment: How can we do the ip check

Comment: You can get the ip data from the incoming request and then check it from your gateway server. I can't tell you how to check it because I don't know what to you do.